# Powershell Select Option Copy, But keep both files - by default

Tags: powershell

I've got this function, that copy files to an directory and rename the duplicates. It's works very well.
But, for any repeated file that was found, it popups the window with the replace, or keep files and rename.

```
   Function Sync-FileArchive
{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
[Alias('sfa')]

Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string]$SourceFiles, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [string]$Destination 
)

$Counter     = 0

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFiles | 
ForEach{
    Try
    {
        If(Test-Path -Path $Destination\$PSItem)
        {
            $Counter++
            Write-Warning -Message "$($PSItem.Name) already exits. Renaming destination file."
            Rename-Item -Path $Destination\$PSItem -NewName "$($PSItem.Basename)_$Counter$($PSitem.Extension)" -Force
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message "$($PSItem.Name) does not exist. Copying file." -Verbose
            Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.Fullname -Destination $Destination     
        }
    }
    Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}}
```

Is there a way to select by default the "Copy, but keep both files" and don't show the window?

[image]

Comment: so ... add a check for the counter that is already in use? [*grin*] personally, i would just use a datestamp with "just enuf granularity" to give unique names.

Comment: @Lee, thanks again for your reply. But, can you explain a little better? What do you mean?

Comment: after you test to see if a file is already at the destination, you can add a check for the counter postfix. however, i would not bother ... just add a `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss` timestamp as the postfix. i doubt you will need any more granularity than seconds ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee, I don't now how to do that.Do you have any example ?

Comment: Is something like this? $timestamp = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ":", "." }
New-Item -Path C:\Test\$timestamp -Type Directory

Comment: yep! i tend to use `$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_-_HH-mm-ss')` since file names have serious limits on things like colons. plus, i usually avoid embedded spaces in file names to sidestep the "if it has a space, it must be quoted" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use below function

```
function Copy-Unique {
    # Copies files to a destination. If a file with the same name already exists in the destination,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending '(x)' after the name, but before the extension. 
    # The 'x' is a numeric sequence value.
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]  # add support for -WhatIf switch
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$SourceFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DestinationFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [string]$Filter = '*',

        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    # create the destination path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$DestinationFolder'"
        New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType 'Directory' -Force | Out-Null
    }
    # get a list of file FullNames in this source folder
    $sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter $Filter -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
    foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
        # split each filename into a basename and an extension variable
        $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)    # this includes the dot

        # get an array of all filenames (names only) of the files with a similar name already present in the destination folder
        $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -File -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
        # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
        # $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

        # construct the new filename
        $newName = $baseName + $extension
        $count = 1
        while ($allFiles -contains $newName) {
            $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $baseName, $count, $extension
            $count++
        }
        # use Join-Path to create a FullName for the file
        $newFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $newName
        Write-Verbose "Copying '$file' as '$newFile'"

        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $newFile -Force
    }
    if ($Recurse) {
        # loop though each subfolder and call this function again
        Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object {
            $newSource = (Join-Path -Path $SourceFolder -ChildPath $_)
            $newDestination = (Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $_)
            Copy-Unique -SourceFolder $newSource -DestinationFolder $newDestination -Filter $Filter -Recurse
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
Copy-Unique -SourceFolder 'D:\Code\PowerShell' -DestinationFolder 'D:\Test' -Recurse -Verbose # -WhatIf
```