# How to copy all PDF files from a directory and its subdirectories to one location?

Tags: linux, powershell, file, pdf, copy

How do I copy all `PDF` files from a directory, and it's subdirectories, to a single directory?

there are actually many more files, and of of somewhat arbitrary depth.  It's fair to assume maximum depth of four directories.

I suppose the files need to renamed, in the event that `a.pdf`, for example, is in several directories.  Because I'll be [adding](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/8774/12205) the files to `Calibre`, duplicates are preferred over leaving out files.  (Not looking to check files against each other for duplicates.)

Following KISS principles:

```
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> Copy-Item -path "/home/nicholas/from" -include "*.pdf" -Destination "/home/nicholas/to"
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> ls /home/nicholas/to
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> ls /home/nicholas/from
one  two
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> tree /home/nicholas/from
/home/nicholas/from
├── one
│   ├── a.pdf
│   ├── b.pdf
│   └── foo.txt
└── two
    ├── bar.txt
    ├── c.pdf
    └── d.pdf

2 directories, 6 files
PS /home/nicholas/to>
```

Obviously, the above attempt fails to traverse into sub-directories, and doesn't deal with name clashes.

Probably makes sense to rename each `PDF` as it's copied.  The `recurse` flag seems useful:

```
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> ls
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> Copy-Item -Path "/home/nicholas/from" -Destination "/home/nicholas/to" -Recurse
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> tree
.
└── from
    ├── one
    │   ├── a.pdf
    │   ├── b.pdf
    │   └── foo.txt
    └── two
        ├── bar.txt
        ├── c.pdf
        └── d.pdf

3 directories, 6 files
PS /home/nicholas/to>
```

not sure how filter out `txt` files and put everything into a single directory, however.

Copying all `PDF` files with [some](https://sid-500.com/2018/02/26/copy-item-and-remove-item-automate-copying-and-deleting-operations/) success:

```
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> ls
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> tree /home/nicholas/from/                                                                                  
/home/nicholas/from/
├── one
│   ├── a.pdf
│   ├── b.pdf
│   └── foo.txt
└── two
    ├── bar.txt
    ├── c.pdf
    └── d.pdf

2 directories, 6 files
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> Get-ChildItem /home/nicholas/from -File -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination /home/nicholas/to -filter '*.pdf'
PS /home/nicholas/to> 
PS /home/nicholas/to> tree
.
├── a.pdf
├── bar.txt
├── b.pdf
├── c.pdf
├── d.pdf
└── foo.txt

0 directories, 6 files
PS /home/nicholas/to>
```

but how do I add some logic to rename and increment the files with a pattern like `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, etc?

Looking to "merge" folders with PDF's to a [single](https://adamtheautomator.com/copy-item/) directory.

Comment: You could use my [Copy-Unique function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65023210/9898643) for that

Comment: @Theo, that's really useful! Will snatch that script if I may

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track for the most part:

```
$PDFs = "C:\"
$i = 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $PDFs -Filter "*.pdf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "C:\NewFileDir" -Verbose}
        
Start-Sleep 3

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\NewFileDir -File "*.pdf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $("$_{0}.pdf" -f $i++) -Verbose}
```

Comment: This will lead to name collisions when files with the same name are already copied to the destination folder. Renaming afterwards won't help there..

Comment: @Theo,  what would be a better approach then? Renaming before hand? I'd suggest copying unique ones but, its the file names that are the same, not the contents.

Comment: Unless we were to rename the unique ones first, then copy over? Or vise-versa.

Comment: Edit: See @Theos, function. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014451/powershell-select-option-copy-but-keep-both-files-by-default/65023210#65023210>

Comment: I'm adding these to `calibre` and so using `calibre` to weed through the duplicates.  Would rather have duplicates than to miss files.  At least in this scenario.  Pruning files seems a seperate process.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly works:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/files$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/files$ pwsh copy_pdfs.ps1 
Copy-Item: /home/nicholas/powershell/files/copy_pdfs.ps1:9
Line |
   9 |      Copy-Item -path $pdf -Destination /home/nicholas/to/$i.pdf
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: The
     | possible origins of 2019-nCoV coronavirus [DOI 10.13140@RG.22.21799.29601] [originsof2019-n

Copy-Item: /home/nicholas/powershell/files/copy_pdfs.ps1:9
Line |
   9 |      Copy-Item -path $pdf -Destination /home/nicholas/to/$i.pdf
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: The
     | possible origins of 2019-nCoV coronavirus [DOI 10.13140@RG.22.21799.29601] [originsof2019-n

done
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/files$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/files$ cat copy_pdfs.ps1 





$file = Get-ChildItem /home/nicholas/pdfs -filter *.pdf -recurse 
$i = 1                           
foreach ($pdf in $file) {            
    Copy-Item -path $pdf -Destination /home/nicholas/to/$i.pdf
    $i++              
}

$file = Get-ChildItem -filter *.pdf -recurse 




write-host "done"
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/files$
```

criticism or alternate solutions appreciated.  Thanks to weq on IRC for the logic.

Comment: You can use `Copy-Item` to do your filtering. `Copy-Item -Path $pdf -Filter "*.pdf" -Destination \\-\-\-`