# How to replicate the tree command from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, tree, get-childitem, calibre

Looking to build a tree of directories and files, with output quite similar to that of the `tree` command.  With the additional functionality that the actual files can be piped to powershell in order to, for example, here, search with `regex` through the files.

---

The `Calibre` library [holds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66289392/4531180) a number of files.

Attempting to [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18847285/4531180) through its directories and sub-directories:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "/home/nicholas/Calibre Library/"

foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName + "out" 
    Get-Content $f.FullName | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9') } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

But, that just generates pages of errors:

```
  11 |      Get-Content $f.FullName | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'step4' -or $ …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to get content because it is a directory: '/home/nicholas/Calibre Library/Unknown'. Please use
     | 'Get-ChildItem' instead.
```

The [notion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66308093/4531180) is to search ".txt" files using `regex`.  First, need to loop through the ".txt" files in the `Calibre` library.

(Or, perhaps, just pass the output of "tree" to powershell?  Might be far more pragmatic?  The 'tree' command certainly works from the REPL console.  At least on Linux.  I'll perhaps make that a seperate question.)

Comment: your post makes very little sense to me. why do you expect to get the content of a DIRECTORY? what on earth are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hopefully the new paragraph at the top gives some context @Lee_Dailey

Comment: You may limit the result of your `Get-ChildItem` command to only files with the parameter `-File`. ;-)

Comment: And you may search for patterns in files a little more efficiantly with the cmdlet `Select-String`

Comment: @NicholasSaunders - thank you for the clarification. [*grin*] ///// as Olaf pointed out, the faster/safer methods would be to grab ONLY files with the `G-CI` call AND to use a `-Filter` to get only txt files. then feed the `.FullFileName` value into `Select-String` using it's `-Path` parameter. finally, use the gathered info to build a `[PSCustomObject]` that has only the properties you want.