# copying a file to a remote location with a random number added to the name

Tags: powershell, copy-item

The following code does some queries locally on individual servers, and the desired result is accomplished.  However I want to copy these files to a remote directory on our network for easy access.  The issue I have run into is that I have added a random number to the file name to keep them unique, but how do I call the randomly named file to be copied. Obviously this would be easier without the random number, but I will be dumping multiple files into the desired directory. (also I commented out the remote location, as I have not settled on a directory yet)  Hope that makes sense

=============================================================================

```
#Creates folder for the files to be stored
New-Item -Path 'C:\temp\ServerQuery' -ItemType Directory

#Grabs Device Name and Local user Accounts

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" |
  Select PSComputername, Name, Status, Disabled, AccountType, Lockout, PasswordRequired, PasswordChangeable, SID | Export-Csv C:\temp\ServerQuery\DeviceandUserAccounts.csv


Get-LocalGroup | Select Name, Objectclass, Principalsource, sid| Export-Csv C:\temp\ServerQuery\LocalGroup.csv 

    #Converts files to Excel workbook with Each file on a different sheet

    $path="C:\temp\ServerQuery" #target folder
    cd $path;

    $csvs = Get-ChildItem .\* -Include *.csv
    $y=$csvs.Count
    Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($y)"
    foreach ($csv in $csvs)
    {
    Write-Host " "$csv.Name
    }

    #Random added to place a random variable in the file name so we do not have duplicates
    $Random = Get-Random
    $outputfilename = $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy) + "_" + $env:USERNAME +"_" + "$Random" + 
    "_Server_Query.xlsx" #creates file name with date/username
    Write-Host Creating: $outputfilename
    $excelapp = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
    $excelapp.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvs.Count
    $xlsx = $excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
    $sheet=1

    foreach ($csv in $csvs)
    {
    $row=1
    $column=1
    $worksheet = $xlsx.Worksheets.Item($sheet)
    $worksheet.Name = $csv.Name
    $file = (Get-Content $csv)
    foreach($line in $file)
    {
    $linecontents=$line -split ',(?!\s*\w+")'
    foreach($cell in $linecontents)
    {
    $worksheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $cell
    $column++
    }
    $column=1
    $row++
    }
    $sheet++
    }
    $output = $path + "\" + $outputfilename
    $xlsx.SaveAs($output)
    $excelapp.quit()
    cd \ #returns to drive root

    #Remove .csv files from folder in order to keep clean for the next query

    Remove-Item -path C:\temp\ServerQuery\*.csv*

    #Copy files to \\filesvr\GLOBAL drive for access
    #$remoteFilePath = '\\filesvr\GLOBAL\File.txt'
    #Copy-Item -Path C:\File.txt -Destination $remoteFilePath
    #Write-Host "I've just copied the file to $remoteFilePath"
```

Comment: You have the full path with the exact name of the file, including the random number, stored in `$output`. `Copy-Item -path $output -destination $remoteFilePath` should do what you want, right?

Comment: Adding a random number doesn't guarantee a unique filename. Better would be to add more of the date to it like `HHmmssfff`, or the `.Ticks` property. You could also opt for adding a GUID: `(New-Guid).Guid`. You could also choose to first check if the proposed filename is unique and if not add a sequal number to it. As for copying multiple files to a destination, while ensuring unique filenames, you can use my function [Copy-Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65023210/9898643)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @TheMadTechnician , I think I was overthinking it a bit.  Still trying to find my way around Powershell.  Worked perfectly