# PowerShell Copy All Files in Folders and Sub=Folders Not older than 300 minutes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy all files in folders and sub-folders not older than 300 minutes, but the code I got working only copies the files in the main folder, it doesn't copy the files in subfolders.
At the destination I don't want to maintain the folder structure of the original files, I just want to put all the origin files into a single specific destination folder.
This is the code I have:

```
Powershell -NoL -NoP -C "&{$ts=New-TimeSpan -M 300;"^
 "Get-ChildItem "C:\Origin" -Filter '*.dat'|?{"^
 "$_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date)-$ts)}|"^
 %%{Copy-Item $_.FullName 'C:\Destination'}}"
```

Could someone help me out please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you running PowerShell from cmd? And, what to do with duplicate file names ?

Comment: Pass `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: @zett42 you mean this:
"Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Origin" -Filter '*.dat'|?{"^
It did not work.

Comment: @Theo PowerShell from command because I need a batch file. What would you suggest for duplicate names? I didn't think about that.

Comment: You could use function [Copy-Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65023210/9898643) and save in a .ps1 file. Then, from cmd you can start PowerShell to run that file

Comment: @Theo Can Copy-Unique copy files not created more than 300 minutes ago? What is the code? Ps1 vs bat is not my concern at the moment, my concern is making this work.

Comment: Not without a small modification: `$sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter $Filter -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-300).Date }).FullName`

Comment: @Theo now I know that you are a guru holding back and that I have no idea about PS. Could you provide me the whole code? Where do I insert the origin folder path? And the destination? The the file types?

Comment: Ok, I can help with that, but I'm on mobile now. Tomorrow ok?

Comment: @Theo No problem, I really appreciate your help, I am really sorry for the trouble but this has nothing to do with what I am used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified script for you you can save as "Copy-Unique.ps1" you can run from a batch file.

```
function Copy-Unique {
    # Copies files to a destination. If a file with the same name already exists in the destination,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending '(x)' after the name, but before the extension. 
    # The 'x' is a numeric sequence value.
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]  # add support for -WhatIf switch
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$SourceFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DestinationFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$NewerThanMinutes = -1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$Filter = '*',

        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    # create the destination path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$DestinationFolder'"
        $null = New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    }
    # get a list of file FullNames in this source folder
    $sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter $Filter -File -Recurse:$Recurse)
    # if you want only files not older than x minutes, apply an extra filter
    if ($NewerThanMinutes -gt 0) {
        $sourceFiles = @($sourceFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$NewerThanMinutes) })
    }
    foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
        # get an array of all filenames (names only) of the files with a similar name already present in the destination folder
        $destFiles = @((Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -File -Filter "$($file.BaseName)*$($file.Extension)").Name)
        # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
        # $destFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

        # construct the new filename
        $newName = $file.Name
        $count = 1
        while ($destFiles -contains $newName) {
            $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $file.BaseName, $count++, $file.Extension
        }
        # use Join-Path to create a FullName for the file
        $newFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $newName
        Write-Verbose "Copying '$($file.FullName)' as '$newFile'"

        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -Force
    }
}

# you can change the folder paths, file pattern to filter etc. here
$destFolder = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Destination' -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}' -f (Get-Date))
Copy-Unique -SourceFolder "C:\Origin" -DestinationFolder $destFolder -Filter '*.dat' -Recurse -NewerThanMinutes 300
```

---

Changed the code to now take a `datetime` object to compare against rather than an amount of minutes. This perhaps makes the code easier to understand, but certainly more flexible.

```
function Copy-Unique {
    # Copies files to a destination. If a file with the same name already exists in the destination,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending '(x)' after the name, but before the extension. 
    # The 'x' is a numeric sequence value.
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]  # add support for -WhatIf switch
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$SourceFolder,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DestinationFolder,

        [string]$Filter = '*',

        [datetime]$NewerThan = [datetime]::MinValue,

        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    # create the destination path if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$DestinationFolder'"
        $null = New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    }
    # get a list of file FullNames in this source folder
    $sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter $Filter -File -Recurse:$Recurse)
    # if you want only files newer than a certain date, apply an extra filter
    if ($NewerThan -gt [datetime]::MinValue) {
        $sourceFiles = @($sourceFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $NewerThan })
    }
    foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
        # get an array of all filenames (names only) of the files with a similar name already present in the destination folder
        $destFiles = @((Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -File -Filter "$($file.BaseName)*$($file.Extension)").Name)
        # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
        # $destFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

        # construct the new filename
        $newName = $file.Name
        $count = 1
        while ($destFiles -contains $newName) {
            $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $file.BaseName, $count++, $file.Extension
        }
        # use Join-Path to create a FullName for the file
        $newFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $newName
        Write-Verbose "Copying '$($file.FullName)' as '$newFile'"

        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -Force
    }
}

# you can change the folder paths, file pattern to filter etc. here
$destFolder = Join-Path -Path 'D:\Destination' -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}' -f (Get-Date))
Copy-Unique -SourceFolder "C:\Origin" -DestinationFolder $destFolder -Filter '*.dat' -Recurse -NewerThan (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-300)
```

---

When you have saved the above code to let's say 'C:\Scripts\Copy-Unique.ps1' you can then call it from a batch file like:

```
Powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "C:\Scripts\Copy-Unique.ps1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Theo
I am now facing a new problem due to the fact that I am now using a bat file and a ps1 file.
I changed the last line of the ps1 code in order to produce folder name with a date in this format: [2022-05-02]
Like this:
Copy-Unique -SourceFolder "C:\Origin" -DestinationFolder "C:\Destination\[$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))]" -Filter '*.dat' -Recurse -NewerThanMinutes 300
Unfortunately I get a lot of errors...

Comment: @JorgeLobo That's because you use double-qoutes inside double-qoutes, but mainly because of the square brackets in that path. Better do round brackets like `"C:\Destination_($((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')))"`. For square brackets, you need to change every `-Path` parameter into `-LiteralPath`, but I would advise against it because you will create problems with those for everything you want to do later..

Comment: @JorgeLobo Explanation: The `-Path` parameter for Get-ChildItem, Test-Path etc. can use `wildcard` characters like the asteriks `*` and also the square brackets `[]`. The problem is that if a path contains these square brackets, PowerShell treats them as wildcard characters and the cmdlet will fail. Using `-LiteralPath` instead takes the path string literally and does not try to interpret any of the characters.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Inserting ' ' ' ' or " " " " somewhere in the code?

Comment: @JorgeLobo A workaround for the square brackets you mean? No, this is what it is. If you have square brackets in a path, use `-LiteralPath`, otherwise these characters are interpreted as [Wildcard characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4). Windows will allow `[]` in a path, but if you intend to do more with PowerShell, you are creating extra problems in the future..

Comment: @JorgeLobo Actually, you _can_ escape them, but that is a real pain and I think I wouldn't want that. Anyway, if you want to experiment with that, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/268289/1131396)

Comment: No more [[[]]] for me, I just removed it out of the folder name... Now I have a new challenge. the following code is not properly working: Copy-Unique -SourceFolder "C:\Origin" -DestinationFolder "C:\Destination\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))_$((Get-Date).ToString("HH-mm"))" -Filter '*.dat' -Recurse -NewerThanMinutes 300
The time filter for files newer than 300 minutes is not working at all, is there a solution?

Comment: **LastWriteTime** is fine, thank you very much. With the last change you made to the code, the `-NewerThanMinutes 300` stopped working, it no longer finds any files younger than 300 minutes.

Comment: you are missing the closing brackets `[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]` after I put the closing brackets, I am still not getting the files newer than 300 minutes, the script is copying all the files.

Comment: @JorgeLobo Please try my alternative code

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all the effort.
Could you check the alternative code? It is not running on my machine.

Comment: @JorgeLobo Just tested (with different paths of course) and it works as intended